# Getting an injector moduler error in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I know this question has been asked many times and I've had a look at many of the answers and none seem

Here is the error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.9

here is script.js:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('tictactoe',['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.label='hello world';

console.log($scope.label);
}]);
```

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe Game</h1>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="tictactoe">
<label id="label">{{label}}</label>
</body>
</html>
```

I’m sure the answer is straight forward, but I can't for the life of me see which it is.

Comment: your code is working https://jsfiddle.net/pvfkxdby/ whats the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why it's not working. Could it be an installation issue?

Comment: When you are debugging with angular you should not use the minified version. The errors produced from the minified version are not friendly. Instead remove the .min and try again (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js). See if that gives you a better error to work with.

Comment: the script tag should have been script.js not app.js